# Dynamic and static MenuItems, both in MainMenu and ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I whould like to have a menu like the following:

```
┌──────────────────────────┐
│ MenuItem always the same │
│ <Separator />            │
│ MenuItem read from XML 1 │
│ MenuItem read from XML 2 │
│ MenuItem read from XML n │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

And this should be reused in a MainMenu and as a submenu of a ContextMenu also.

I currently have the following in the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ItemTypes" Source="C:\Config.xml"
        XPath="Configuration/ItemTypes/ItemType" />

    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="mnuAdd" x:Shared="False">
        <MenuItem Command="local:MainWindow.AddItemGroup" Header="Item Group" />
        <Separator />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemTypes}}" />
    </collections:ArrayList>

</Window.Resources>
```

And have the following in the XML:

```
<Configuration>
    <ItemTypes>
        <ItemTypeName="Item1" DisplayName="First Item" />
        <ItemTypeName="Item2" DisplayName="Second Item" />
    </ItemTypes>
</Configuration>
```

And of course I have HierarchicalDataTemplate, but it never displays right.

If I set it to this one:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="ItemType">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@DisplayName, StringFormat={}{0}}"
            Tag="{Binding XPath=@Name}" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddItemMenu_Click"
            MouseRightButtonUp="AddItemMenu_Click" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

It displays this way:

[image]

If I set it to this one:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="ItemType">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding XPath=@DisplayName, StringFormat={}{0}}"
            Tag="{Binding XPath=@Name}" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddItemMenu_Click" 
            MouseRightButtonUp="AddItemMenu_Click" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

It displays this way:

[image]

**How can I style it to display correctly as normal menu items?**

*Please not that according to previous research, having `<collections:ArrayList x:Key="mnuAdd" x:Shared="False">` is mandatory as I want the same static resource to be displayed both in MainMenu and in ContextMenu. If I don't use this, one of them disappears.*

**UPDATE 1:**

According to H.B. changed the `<collections:ArrayList>` to `CompositeCollection`:

```
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="mnuAdd" x:Shared="False">
        <MenuItem Command="local:MainWindow.AddItemGroup" Header="Item Group" />
        <Separator />
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemTypes}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
```

Now if my DataTemplate is `MenuItem`, it still displays awkward:

[image]

If my DataTemplate is `TextBlock`, it displays fine, but the clicks are only handled if it is *on the text*, not if it is a little left from the text.

[image]

**How can I make it work good and look good?**

**Edit 2:**
Managed to solved the click issue by extending the `TextBlock` horizontally by the following:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="ItemType">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@DisplayName, StringFormat={}{0}}"
            Tag="{Binding XPath=@Name}" MouseLeftButtonUp="AddItemMenu_Click" 
            MouseRightButtonUp="AddTestItemMenu_Click"
            Margin="-30,0,-60,0" Padding="30,0,60,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now it looks good and works well.

Comment: You should make the static resource no-shared instead...

Comment: How exactly does it solve the display issue?

Comment: Well, actually you could solve it by not putting any UI-elements into your list and letting the `Menu`/`ContextMenu` handle the creation of the UI, but i guess using `x:Shared` here is viable...

Comment: Yes, you are right, x:Shared is mandatory, otherwise it is not possible to display the same dynamic content at different places. It works well by the way, all I need now is some styling so it would also look well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) to build your list, use a [`CollectionContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectioncontainer.aspx) for the dynamic part.

Comment: I started with this approach. With this, the following happens: if I open MainMenu, items display. Then if I open ContextMenu, items display. From this moment, the items are bound to ContextMenu, and whenever I open MainMenu again, items won't display. That is what I indicated in the italic text at the end of my question.

Comment: @user2270404: I did not tell you to drop the `x:Shared` in my answer, that is a different issue that can be handled one way or another.

Comment: I either use collections:ArrayList or CompositeCollection. CompositeCollection can't have x:Shared.

Comment: @user2270404: Why would that be?

Comment: You are saying I should put a `<CompositeCollection>` inside the `<collections:ArrayList>` ?

Comment: @user2270404: No, of course not. By why would should you not be able to use `x:Shared` on a `CompositeCollection`?

Comment: I see your point, now this is getting me closer. I have updated the question incorporating your advice.

Comment: Updated question with my solution. I will mark accept your answer because it drove me to the right direction. Many thanks for the help. P.S. Please keep title intact ;-)

Comment: @user2270404: You don't seem to understand how this site works. 1. All content belongs to the community. 2. This being said established users may edit *your* content. 3. Tags do *not* belong in the title, this has been established on meta a long time ago, we have a tag section for a reason. 4. Answers do not belong in the question, if you have a complete answer to give, then post it *as an answer*.