# WPF: Contextmenu MenuItem with static and dynamic entries and Command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu, contextmenu

I have a Contextmenu which contains MenuItems. So far, so good.
In a submenu ("Colors"), I want to have static entries ("Reset color" and "Custom color") as well a dynamic values. It currently looks like this:
[Contextmenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYaED.png).

So, my question is:

**What do I need to do to get the same styling for both: static and dynamic (via my CustomColorCollection) entries and still have the possibility to separately set the Command and CommandParameter?**

The dynamic values are bound to a
`public static ObservableCollection<ContextMenuColor> ColorList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuColor>()` 
with ContextMenuColor being a small class like this:

```
    public class ContextMenuColor
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public ContextMenuColor(string title, string color)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Color = color;
        }
    }
```

When I click on a menuitem, I want it to run my ICommand SetColorCommand with ContextMenuColor.Color as a CommandParameter.

This is what I have so far in my XAML:

```
<MenuItem Header="Colors">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomColorCollection" Source="{Binding ColorList}"/>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="Reset color" Command="{Binding SetColorCommand}" CommandParameter="#DCDCDC" UsesItemContainerTemplate="False">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#DCDCDC"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Custom color" Command="{Binding SetColorCommand}" CommandParameter="custom" UsesItemContainerTemplate="False">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF00" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC500FF" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF0A7D8F" Offset="0.5"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomColorCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> <!-- this should only be used for the CustomColorCollection -->
            <MenuItem x:Name="MyMenuItem" Header="{Binding Title}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Color}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>  <!-- this should only be used for the CustomColorCollection -->
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetColorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

P.S.: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921617/dynamic-and-static-menuitems-both-in-mainmenu-and-contextmenu) helped but is still a little different from my problem as I was unable to set Command and CommandParameter for the proposed TextBlock in the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

I now have a working solution!

First thing: I do not have to use a DataTemplate at all.
Second was to add a rectangle in the Resources:
       `<Rectangle x:Key="ColorRectangle" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Color}" />`

Third thing was to change the ItemContainerStyle to use the defined `<Rectangle>` and also use the general style for MenuItems (via `BasedOn`):

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ColorRectangle}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetColorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For completeness, this is the full code:

```
<MenuItem Header="Colors">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomColorCollection" Source="{Binding ColorList}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Key="ColorRectangle" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Color}" />
    </MenuItem.Resources>
    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="Reset color" Command="{Binding SetColorCommand}" CommandParameter="#DCDCDC" UsesItemContainerTemplate="False">
                <!--this is TextColorBrush-->
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#DCDCDC"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Custom color" Command="{Binding SetColorCommand}" CommandParameter="custom" UsesItemContainerTemplate="False">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF00" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC500FF" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF0A7D8F" Offset="0.5"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomColorCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ColorRectangle}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SetColorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Only one question remains: for the static entries (i.e. "Reset color" and "Custom color") I get these warnings in the Output window of Visual Studio 2017:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Title' property not found on 'object' ''SoundtrackRow' (HashCode=9307971)'. BindingExpression:Path=Title; DataItem='SoundtrackRow' (HashCode=9307971); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'object' ''SoundtrackRow' (HashCode=9307971)'. BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem='SoundtrackRow' (HashCode=9307971); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

They are, of course, since the static entries can not bind to Title and Color as they simply do not exist for them.

**How can I get rid of these warnings?**